# How can I bind function with hooks in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

Basically we bind event handler functions in constructor or make them as arrow functions in React class components like below

```
class Test extends Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = { count:0 };
    this.setCount = this.setCount.bind(this);
  }

  setCount() {
    this.setState({count: this.state.count + 1});
  }

  render() {
    return <button onClick={this.setCount}>Increase</button>
  }
}
```

But after hooks are introduced in React v16.7.0 the class components became functional components with state.

So how can I bind the function with hooks in functional component?

Comment: There is no need to bind the function in a function component since you are not using `this`.

Comment: you don't need if you use the arrow function

Comment: Ok what if I use Redux connect method with mapStateToProps. How can I access props in functional component like this.props or just props?

Comment: You just use props ... not this.props

Answer (score 68, accepted):

There's no need to bind functions/callbacks in functional components since there's no `this` in functions. In classes, it was important to bind `this` because we want to ensure that the `this` in the callbacks referred to the component's instance itself. However, doing `.bind` in the constructor has another useful property of creating the functions *once* during the entire lifecycle of the component and a new callback wasn't created in every call of `render()`. To do only initialize the callback once using React hooks, you would use `useCallback`.

#### Classes

```
class Foo extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick() {
    console.log('Click happened');
  }

  render() {
    return <Button onClick={this.handleClick}>Click Me</Button>;
  }
}
```

#### Hooks

```
function Foo() {
  const memoizedHandleClick = useCallback(
    () => {
      console.log('Click happened');
    },
    [], // Tells React to memoize regardless of arguments.
  );
  return <Button onClick={memoizedHandleClick}>Click Me</Button>;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Can’t I write event handler function like const memoizedHandleClick = () => {
      console.log('Click happened');
    } ?

Comment: @Think-Twice yes, you can. But it will recreate handler on each render(the same as using arrow functions in class-based `render()`).

Comment: Ok what is useCallback? Is it predefined name?

Comment: Yes it's another hook. Have you read the docs? You should check out the whole section on hooks: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html

Answer (score 5):

People come to SO and copy-paste code. Leaving this answer here, so the React community doesn't go around incorrectly memoizing everything and potentially doing more work than necessary.

### Function components

```
function Foo() {
  const handleClick = function(){
    // use function statements to avoid creating new instances on every render
    // when you use `bind` or arrow functions
    console.log('memoizing can lead to more work!')
  };
  return <Button onClick={handleClick}>Click Me</Button>;
}
```

Tip: look at what code is transpiled when using `useCallback` and see if it's necessary, before dropping it in. if you're not sure you need it, you probably don't. and to be sure it's doing you good, profile it.

Comment: Hey so I'm having an issue with my code like this function Foo() {
  const handleClick = () => {
    //
    //
  };
  return <Button onClick={handleClick}>Click Me</Button>;
} Where I'm seeing potential old click handlers in memory and they trigger on rerenders? It's a really strange occurance and quite rare but maybe you can help? You seem to know a lot about this but can't find any docs on it!!

Answer (score -2):

You might as well write the component `Foo` above like this and save yourself some typing. Note the syntax around handleClick ... it defines the closure handleClick as a field on Foo, rather than as a method. This removes the need for you to use bind to overwrite the OBject's 'handleClick' reference in the constructor. (Also, you don't need to define a constructor if you're just calling 'super'!)

```
class Foo extends Component {
  handleClick = () => {
    console.log('Click happened');
  }

  render() {
    return <Button onClick={this.handleClick}>Click Me</Button>;
  }
}
```

Similarly, for your original example, just declare state and setCount directly and to simplify your code:

```
class Test extends Component{
  state = {count: 0}

  setCount = () => {
    this.setState({count: this.state.count + 1});
  }

  render() {
    return <button onClick={this.setCount}>Increase</button>
  }
}
```

Comment: This is just an alternate approach to addressing the binding issue for class components. OP is asking how this is addressed for function components.