# ReactJS - How can I transform a Class Component withsSide-effects of combined state updates to a Functional Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm working with [ftw-hourly](https://github.com/sharetribe/ftw-hourly) and specifically [on this file](https://github.com/sharetribe/ftw-hourly/blob/master/src/components/EditListingLocationPanel/EditListingLocationPanel.js) I would like to transform it into a functional component (due to some state management that I need to do with Mapbox - I wish to get a location from [Mapbox](https://docs.mapbox.com/help/tutorials/local-search-geocoding-api/) and populate the form input fields with the info retrieved from the search).

However, I'm having some problems figuring out what I should do about `getInitialValues` when turning the component into a functional one.

Is my task achievable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the problem that functional components don't have methods? If so, you can create functions inside other functions (a function inside your functional component), like this:

```
import React from 'react';

const MyFunctionalComponent = (props) => {

    const getInitialValues = function(){
        ...rest of function...
    }

    return ( ... );
};
```

Then, you can call `getInitialValues()` instead of `this.getInitialValues()`, and `props` instead of `this.props`

Comment: You're absolutely right, Daniel. 
I ended up searching a bit more and I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53215067/how-can-i-bind-function-with-hooks-in-react) solution for my ```getInitialValues```function and and I used ```const [initialValues, setInitialValues] = useState(getInitialValues);```afterwards