# I am trying to use callback in hook but can not get latest context value in the callback

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

```
const Demo = () => {
  const { name } = useContext(AppContext);
  function emiterCallback(val) {
    console.log('value==', name);
    if (name !== val) {
       setContextState({ name: val });
    }
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    window.eventEmitter.on('CHANGED', emiterCallback);
    return () => {
      window.eventEmitter.removeListener('CHANGED', emiterCallback);
    };
  }, []);
}
```

in class component
this.emiterCallback = this.emiterCallback.bind(this)  can solve my question, but how to use it in hook ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you have here is due to the fact that `useEffect` with an empty array dependency only runs once - when the component mounts. This means that the `emiterCallback` it assigns as the event function is the very first one that's made on the first render. Since you just declare `emiterCallback` in the body of the function, it gets remade every single re-render, so after a single re-render, it will be a different one to the event one you assigned when the component mounted. Try something like this:

```
import React, { useCallback, useContext, useEffect } from 'react';

...

const Demo = () => {
  const { name } = useContext(AppContext);

  // Assign it to a memoized function that will recalculate as needed when the context value changes
  const emiterCallback = useCallback((val) => {
    console.log('value==', name);
    if (name !== val) {
       setContextState({ name: val });
    }
  }, [name]);

  // Adding the function as a dependency means the .on function should be updated as needed
  useEffect(() => {
    window.eventEmitter.on('CHANGED', emiterCallback);
    return () => {
      window.eventEmitter.removeListener('CHANGED', emiterCallback);
    };
  }, [emiterCallback]);
}
```

This code isn't tested but you get the idea

Comment: yes man, it solved my issue, thank you very much ^.^

Answer (score 1):

use `useCallback` to memorize the effect no need for bind since there is no this as it is not a class,
Here read more about it -
[How can I bind function with hooks in React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53215067/how-can-i-bind-function-with-hooks-in-react)